# matrix-vector derivative and scalar-vector derivative

Tags: derivatives, matrix-calculus

I have several derivatives need to be calculated. I was wondering whether it's correct or not.

Assume $x\in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 1}$, then

- matrix-vector: $$\frac{\partial x x^\top}{\partial x}  = ? $$
- scalar-vector: $$\frac{\partial x^\top x}{\partial x} = ? $$
- vector-vector: $$\frac{\partial x x^\top x}{\partial x} =? $$
- vector-vector: $$\frac{\partial x^\top x x^\top}{\partial x} =? $$
- vector-vector: $$\frac{\partial x x^\top x}{\partial x^\top} =? $$
- vector-vector: $$\frac{\partial x^\top x x^\top}{\partial x^\top} =? $$

I take a look at the matrix cookbook, but still get confused about this examples.
Could anyone provide detailed steps to get the results by applying the product rule?

Comment: Compute the partial derivatives and order them as you like. When it comes to non-vector calculus, you need to be careful how to represent a derivative. The computation however is just like the vector case.

Answer (score 1):

Start with the scalar-vector case. Write the function in terms of the inner product, then find the differential and then the gradient.
$$\eqalign{
 \phi &= x^Tx = x\cdot x \cr
d\phi &= 2x\cdot dx \cr
\nabla_x\phi &= 2x \cr\cr
}$$
Next up is the vector-vector case.
$$\eqalign{
 y &= xx^Tx = x\phi \cr
dy &= \phi\,dx + x\,d\phi  &= (\phi\,I + 2xx)\cdot dx \cr
\nabla_x y &= \phi\,I + 2xx^T \cr\cr
}$$
Next is the matrix-vector case, but I'm not sure how to handle that since the result is a 3rd order tensor.

Comment: Consider the scalar-vector case: $\Phi = x^\top x \Rightarrow d\Phi  = dx^\top x + x^\top dx \Rightarrow d \Phi = ?$